# Retrieve directory Structure on my Android phone

Tags: android, android-file

I have this requirement to retrieve the phone's complete directory structure (Similar to what comes up when we connect our Android device to DDMS and then click on File Explorer). Is there any API's in Android or java that will help me retrieve this directory listing ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
File f = new File("/");
File file[] = f.listFiles();
for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
{
    Log.d("Files", "FileName:" + file[i].getName());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried simply call something like this?

```
File f = new File("/");
File[] files = f.listFiles();
```

But anyway, you can't get access to folders with non-public read permissions without root, such as /data.

Answer (score 0):

If "complete" is the key word here, then no. An app only has access to its allocated "data" folder, as well as "external" (SD) shared storage.

(Note that the story is different on rooted devices, such as emulators, but that is generally not an option.)

Comment: Not exactly - there are a lot of other accessible areas as well, but you are right that there are some notably inaccessible areas.

Comment: would there be a way for me to read the DDMS tool's File Explorer output ?